# xlsx convert date format to random number

Tags: node.js, typescript, xlsx

I am passing a file to this function and i want to cnvert the data to json but for the specific column DOB 05-04-2001 to random number such as 36986. I want the exact date entered as a response from this function, How to do this ? Can anyone help me out yrr.

```
static convertExcelFileToJsonUsingXlsxTrimSpaces = (path: string) => {
    // Read the file using pathname
    const file = xlsx.readFile(path);

    // Grab the sheet info from the file
    const sheetNames = file.SheetNames;
    const totalSheets = sheetNames.length;

    // Variable to store our data
    const parsedData: any[] = [];

    // Loop through sheets
    for (let i = 0; i < totalSheets; i += 1) {
      // Convert to json using xlsx

      const sheetData = xlsx.utils.sheet_to_json(file.Sheets[sheetNames[i]], { raw: true });

      console.log(sheetData);

      // Process each row to handle tab-separated values
      const processedData: any[] = [];
      sheetData.forEach((row: any) => {
        const processedRow: any = {};
        Object.keys(row).forEach((key) => {
          processedRow[key] = row[key].toString().trim(); // Convert to string and trim whitespace
        });
        processedData.push(processedRow);
      });

      // Add the sheet's processed data to our data array
      parsedData.push(...processedData);
    }

    return parsedData;
  };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not random number, it's default parsing for date cells.

To get date value, add `cellDates: true` flag to parsing options:

Try this:

```
const sheetData = xlsx.utils.sheet_to_json(file.Sheets[sheetNames[i]], { raw: true, cellDates: true });
```

see the docs:

> By default, Excel stores dates as numbers with a format code that
> specifies date processing. For example, the date 19-Feb-17 is stored
> as the number 42785 with a number format of d-mmm-yy
>
> The default behavior for all parsers is to generate number cells.
> Setting cellDates to true will force the generators to store dates.
>
> https://www.npmjs.com/package/xlsx#dates

Answer (score 0):

Adding `cellDates` to the `utils.sheet_to_json` function doesn't really work.

What worked for me was a comment I found [here](https://github.com/SheetJS/sheetjs/issues/721#issuecomment-313732443).

XLS files always store dates as numeric codes. To get the date objects, change the first line to:

```js
var workbook = XLSX.readFile(filePath, {cellDates:true});
```

This is explained [here](https://sheetjs.gitbooks.io/docs/#dates).